# ios MediaPlayer video small window not working

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mpmovieplayer

i have a video playing with MediaPlayer , ok on iPad,

but if I touch the button to make the screen go small
[image]

the minimize icon ... the image disappear,

so what do i use here? to make it go small? `MPMovieScalingMode`?
and how to use it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, figured it out, stupid mistake,

I just had to set the frame for my player

> ```
>    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(100, 300, 300, 300);
> ```

haha,